# How to copy millions files from dedicated server to AWS EC2?

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp, amazon-ec2, lftp

I have a website that needs to move from a dedicated server to AWS EC2 instance. I have 650GB+ data and 3+ million files.

I tried using **SCP** like this but because of huge file it taking so much time.

```
scp -r remote_username@10.10.0.2:/remote/directory /local/directory
```

My Source OS is Centos 7.5 with cPanel. 1TB HDD and 650GB data, the destination server is Ubuntu 18.04, 700GB HDD.

I know we have some other option also like LFTP, SFTP, rSync etc, please help me with quickest method.

Comment: Please Edit the question (to the bottom left of the question text) to indicate the OS of the source machine, and any other specifications like confirming exact copy.

Comment: If you're willing to spend money, there are commercial file-transfer solutions which are much faster than scp, rsync, or sftp.

Comment: @Kenster Thank you but I already started using SCP and almost 50% completed so in this situation I don't want to spend money on transfer files.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest zipping the files in say 1 GB chunks and uploading those.
When unzipping each file is checked against a CRC checksum.  You can use built-in splitting so zip automatically generates .z00 .z01 .z02 .z03 ...

Alternatively, you can use the rar format which allows creation of parity data to repair damaged segments.

Answer (score 0):

There is one AWS Solution how to transfer your data:

https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/?nc1=h_ls

As I know, you'll get a device (via Post Service like DHL) 
You can copy your data on this device and then Amazon will upload this data for you.

Comment: I can't understand why I will need the device, I can copy all files via the web, I know I can do this using SCP, lftp, rsync, sftp but I want to know which one is fast and no risk for data missing. If possible then need some help with SSH command.

Comment: @user219457 please Edit the original question with your specifications.  You've found some of the right tools, and figuring out how to use those is important.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to speed the upload is to do it in multiple parts in parallel.

If you can divide the job among several computers using distinct connections,
this will speed up the upload.

If a single computer does not reach full throughput, you can opt for a
multi-thread method where each thread will open its own connection in parallel.

See the post
[Which is the fastest way to copy 400G of files from an ec2 elastic block store volume to s3?](https://serverfault.com/questions/386910/which-is-the-fastest-way-to-copy-400g-of-files-from-an-ec2-elastic-block-store-v)
for suggestions of products and scripts.

See also the article
[FS File Sync – Faster File Transfer To Amazon EFS File Systems](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/efs-file-sync-faster-file-transfer-to-amazon-efs-file-systems/).

Answer (score 0):

When using `scp`, it doesn't retry or continue on partially transferred files.

Try using `rsync` instead, e.g.

```
rsync -vuaz remote_username@10.10.0.2:/remote/directory/ /local/directory/
```

Arguments:

- `-v`/`--verbose`               increase verbosity.
- `-u`/`--update`                skip files that are newer on the receiver.
- `-a`/`--archive`               archive mode; equals `-rlptgoD`
- `-z`/`--compress`              compress file data during the transfer.

Comment: My maximum files are images and size is less than 2Mb, do you think rsync will do faster than SCP? I already started copying an 80GB directory, so if I close puty now and start using rsync do you this I will get an issue with already downloaded files?

Comment: With `scp`, once you got transfer error, you've to transfer everything over and over again, as you don't know which files were copied fully, which not. Rsync will make the list of all files which needs to be updated, before copying anything. You can use `rsync` after you used `scp`, so it can continue from the point where `scp` finished. Not sure if it's faster, the speed could be the same.
You can leave putty (to avoid unnecessary changes), once you got any transfer issue, continue with `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing AWS CLI on your dedicated server.

Then use `aws s3` command to transfer the files to your AWS S3 bucket first.

E.g.

```
aws s3 sync local/directory s3://mybucket/local/directory
```

Then transfer back to your local EC2 instance:

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/local/directory local/directory
```

The command is designed to copy large number of files, and it can continue on failure.

You can also decide to serve the files for EC2 instance directly from S3.

Check `aws s3 sync help` for help.